# Will replacing ASP.Net Components with standard html equivalents improve performance?

Tags: html, asp.net, performance

I'm working on improving the performance of an ASP.Net application. I have many ASP.Net components which render as normal html components.

**My Question:**

Will there be an increase in performance if I were to replace some of the `ASP` components with standard html equivalents? Or is the performance barely affected?

**Example:**

*Replacing*

```
<asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server">Hello</asp:Label>
```

*With*

```
<label id="myLabel">Hello</label>
```

Comment: The Have you profiled your application code such that you /know/ using WebControls hurts performance?

Comment: @Dai I don't know what you mean by that.